# Add multiple list inside list - dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have this code

```
    var sections = [];
    
    
    sections.add({'name': 'test', 'qustions' : []});
    sections[0]['qustions'] = {'asd':'qustions 1'};
    sections[0]['qustions'] = {'name':'qustions 2'};

    print(sections);
```

returns

`[{name: test, qustions: {name: qustions 2}}]`

I want it to returns something like

`[{name: test, qustions: [{name: qustions 1},{name: qustions 2}]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use `map[key]=newValue`, it reset the value for that key. what you need here is to perform `add` for list.

```dart
var sections = [];

sections.add({'name': 'test', 'qustions': []});

sections[0]['qustions'].add({'asd': 'qustions 1'});
sections[0]['qustions'].add({'name': 'qustions 2'});
print(sections);
```

You may also like to create model class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `insert` method:

```
  var sections = [];

  sections.add({'name': 'test', 'qustions': []});
  sections[0]['qustions'] = {'name': 'qustions 1'};
  sections.insert(1, {'name': 'qustions 2'});
```

output

```
[{name: test, qustions: [{name: qustions 1},{name: qustions 2}]}]
```